# How can I do a "save as" of a netbeans project, if I want to try and change a program?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans as an IDE for a Java class. Well it is a data algorithms class, but in actuality it is a "Teach yourself Java in a hurry while incorporating data algorithm concepts into the programs you fumble through, having had ZERO experience with Java."

I have my program running for this week. However, I want to make some major changes to it to make it more Javaesque if that makes sense. When I took a Python class, I would simply do a "save as", change the new file around, and then if I wrecked the program into a non functional mess I could snap back in an instant by reloading the original file.

So far with Netbeans the only way I have been able to do this is create new project, then copy and paste the code from the original version, making sure paste it just right in between all the stuff Netbeans places in a new project. Furthermore, when I delete a project...and try to create another with the same name, it tells me that project exists and the folder is not empty even IF I just deleted it!! I am running out of names for "week one project"!

I have now spent precious time essentially being salty about Netbeans. However, if anyone can forgive my ramblings, I would appreciate some suggestions.
Apologies and thanks.

Comment: As far as I know there is no `Save As` for an entire Project in NetBeans (the option is disabled within the **File** menu). If however you place focus on the class you are working on within the editor pane of NetBeans then the `Save As` option becomes available and if used a **Save As** dialog is opened which allows you to place the saved class wherever you like.

Comment: What you can do is copy the entire Project directory (using Windows Explorer) and paste it into a different workspace (directory) anywhere in your system. When you select **Open Project** and the dialog is displayed, just navigate to that new workspace location and select the desired Project folder. Do keep in mind however, NetBeans will open that project and you can have two projects with the same name within the Projects pane of NetBeans. You can work on both projects with the same name in NetBeans.

Comment: You may have already considered these things - but here they are, since they are not mentioned in the question: (1) Use a version control system such as Git or Mercurial. I used to do what you are trying to do (copying files around). Now I can switch between code branches, roll back to earlier states of the code, etc. (2) Write unit tests - especially useful when you want to refactor already-working code. Both (1) and (2) take some investment of (precious) time, for sure. Not much time to learn the basics - but maybe a lot to really become proficient.